# Find and replace multiple words with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to find and replace multiple words within a sentence using javascript. Ideally I would like to take a sentence and replace multiple words within that sentence i.e.

text **WORD 1** text | text **WORD 2** text

How can I replace both WORD1 and WORD2 with independent different words?

i.e.

WORD1= New-word-1

WORD2= New-word-2

here is the code:

[js fiddle code click here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaaf8/)

and to take it one step further I would like to pull new word values from an excel sheet, run a loop with the new words to be replaced and have the output of the new sentences all on one page.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I Modified  your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaaf8/1/). In replace you can pass function as a second parameter.
Inside function you can decide replace value for particular word.

```
var visitorName = "new word 1";
var myOldString = "Hello word1! I hope you enjoy your stay word2.";
var myNewString = myOldString.replace(/word1|word2/g, function(w){

        switch(w){
           case 'word1':
                 return visitorName ;

              case 'word2':
                   return 'new word 1';
          }

    });
```

Comment: This is close, but at the end word2 should also be replaced with new-word2...maybe a better description would be...i.e. hello (dog) I hope you enjoy your stay (day) dog should be replaced with (cat) and day should be replaced with (night)

Comment: I wrote a sample code you can change it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks it works great! If I wanted to run a loop through a list of words in an excel sheet and replace word1/word2 with Column  a1,b1;a2,b2 and continue down the list of words to be replaced, how would this be accomplished?